# Android asynchronous API design

Tags: android, asynchronous, api-design

I'm writing an Android library that is inherently asynchronous (waiting for events from a USB device connected to the micro USB port). Looking at how Android packages implement asynchronous APIs, I found a few different ways:

- Taking a `PendingIntent` and sending it when an event happens (For example: [UsbManager.requestPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#requestPermission(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), [NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch(android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter[],%20java.lang.String[][]))).
- Defining an internal callback interface and taking an instance of it, and then calling it when the event happens (Examples include [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and its subclasses).
- Taking a "broadcast action" as a String and then broadcasting that action (possibly locally using LocalBroadcastManager) ([Example from IntentService documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html)).
- Having a purely synchronous API and letting the caller call it asynchronously (in an AsyncTask for example) (For example: [SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase())).

How should I design my API? And are there any recommendations for when to use each kind of API?

Comment: You could also accept a Handler and send messages to it like SensorManager does (and you can send a Handler from your Activity to a Service - even a remote one - wrapped in a Messenger).

Answer (score 1):

The main question is whether you will desing an API that is synchronous or asynchronous.

**Synchronous API**

- API user will need to create a thread/AsyncTask (or similar) manually, so it's a bit more work on that side.
- it's easier to misuse it - for instance by running a blocking method on the main thread
- it's easier to reason about than the asynchronous API, because the code flow is streamlined and linear.

**Asynchronous API**

- it's safer on the caller side (will never block UI)
- tends to be (a bit) harder to use because of the callbacks (or intents, broadcasts listeners etc.)

If you opt for a synchronous API, you're pretty much done ;)

But if  you opt for the asychronous one, in Android case (as you listed already) - you'll need to decide how the API implementation will notify the caller about the asychronous action being completed (or status being changed etc).

The PendingIntent is ususally used for a limited set of actions (i.e. launch an activity or a service, or send a broadcast). I assume your library client will want to do more varied actions than that.

Broadcasting an action is an option. It will separate the client from the library by "the  intent wall", though. So for instance if your library would like to return some complex data structure to the caller, this data structure would need to be [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to fit into an Intent. Broadcasting is also a way of, well, "broadcasting" something. This means that multiple listeners could pick the message up.

Having that said, I would prefer to use the pure Java solution with callbacks interfaces, unless there is a good reason to use Android-specific solution.

Comment: One drawback of the callback interface approach is that its too easy for an unsuspecting user to forget to unregister the callback. If you go this way you might want to code defensively with WeakReferences and so forth...